# Showing alert when creating a new category in admin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out/learn how creating a custom plugin and calling it from another page in wordpress work.

I created a custom plugin and this plugin contains a function that when called will show the user/admin an alert notification div confirming their action.

When the admin create a new category i would like to display the notification in the header.
So i have this line:

```
add_action('create_category', category_custom_alert(), 10)
```

now since is an action in the wordpress dashboard - where should i place this action call? I placed it under wp-admin/admin-functions.php.

My custom plugin function is as follows:

```
function category_custom_alert() {
    ?>
    <div class="bootstrap-inside" id="category_custom_alert">
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissble" role="alert">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong> Your category has been created successfully.
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

When i run this i am not seeing my custom notification message appear.

Comment: why don't you place that code in your plugin's php file?

Comment: @GrafiCode guess i didn't think about it. I just tried it but i noticed that the notification shows on page load rather than waiting to show once i created a category.

Comment: try hooking `created_category` rather than `create_category`. that should be executed AFTER save. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/

Comment: @GrafiCode i went ahead and tried that but once i clicked add category it seems like the page is just loading and i don't see the notification nor the added category. I refresh the page then i can see the newly added category in the list.